# Is it possible to generate a deadlock between only 2 transactions and 1 resource?

Tags: database, deadlock, theory, database-deadlocks

I thought I knew the answer to this question but this [answer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/isro-isro-cs-2016-question-40/) is giving me doubts.

Taking the following schedule as an example:

r<sub>1</sub>(x) r<sub>2</sub>(x) w<sub>1</sub>(x) w<sub>2</sub>(x)

Could a deadlock occur?
My reasoning is that yes it could occur because Transaction 1 and Transaction 2 will have Shared Locks on resource x, thus not allowing either Transaction to continue with their writes.

So am I correct or is the response in the link I added correct?

Answer (score 0):

The question comes down to how you define "resource". In your example, there is one object X that two threads are reading to and writing from. If there were just one type of lock for the object X, then thread 2 would fail to acquire it when doing its read, no deadlock.

Similarly, if only the writes required a lock (so there's no guarantee of repeatable reads), then thread 2's write would just clobber thread 1's write. Again, no deadlock.

But in your example, there are two kinds of locks against one object. The "resource" here is the lock, and there are two of them: the sharable read lock and the exclusive write lock.

This is why it's a good idea to acquire locks in advance. If both threads tried to acquire a write lock (just one "resource") instead of first acquiring a read lock, and then promoting it to a write lock, then there wouldn't be any contention.